# How to assemble (and re-use) embedded objects in resource classes?

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I have a project where domain classes and REST resources are split up.
My domain model contains classes like `Hotel`, `Customer`, `Country`, `Continent`. Both the `Hotel` and `Customer` model have a reference to the `Country` and `Country` itself has a reference to `Continent`.

In my REST model I have a `HotelResource` and a `CustomerResource` (both extending Spring HATEOAS's `ResourceSupport`).
And to transform from the domain model to REST model I also have assemblers extending `ResourceAssemblerSupport`.

In my REST model I have entities like `Country` and `Continent` but they are not identifiable by a link, there is e.g. no endpoint to retrieve only a country or list all countries.

So a `CountryResource` extending `ResourceSupport` seems not right as `ResourceSupport` implements `Identifiable`.

Country and Resource are some kind of embedded classes for resources.

How should I treat them to re-use the json rendering of them? I mean these embedded `Country` and `Continent` are included in multiple Resource classes and I only want to code the transformation once...

Before using Spring HATEOAS I had my own `Resource` and `ResourceAssembler` classes which I used for both `HotelResource` and `CountryResource` but it could be argued if that is right as `CountryResource` is not really a resource.

I think if your REST model grows this kind of question will raise - e.g.. to re-use logic for embedded objects - and I wonder what the best practices are from Spring HATEOAS library perspective.

Comment: _"included in multiple Resource classes and I only want to code the transformation once"_ Make it so. What's the problem?

Comment: yes it's quiet simple to do that. but it feels like copying 80% of what the Spring HATEOAS resource support/assembler classes are already doing...

Comment: `ResourceAssembler` does almost nothing. You always initialize the resource yourself. So what code could possibly be copied from `ResourceAssembler` if you don't need to do what `ResourceAssembler` does? Without seeing any code I can also assume that `Country` can be used as is, i.e. no transformation is necessary in the first place.

Comment: Country consists of e.g. alpha2 code, alpha3 code, name. So there is transformation going on.

Comment: _"So there is transformation going on"_ You didn't show us any. Anyway,  have a `CountryResource` that does **not** extend `ResourceSupport` and a `CountryResourceFactory` == _"re-use logic for embedded objects"_. Sorry, I still don't see a problem.

Comment: It's not a problem :-) Just wondering how others do this.